# How to use Psexec execute a script on a remote machine without security warning

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute a powershell script remotely using psexec like this:

```
.\psexec.exe \\remotecomputer -u domain\remoteuser -p password powershell.exe -c:\myscript.ps1
```

But the script does get executed remotely, but I see a 'security warning' when it get executed.  On the remote machine, I already set 'Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass' in powershell.  And when I executed the script 'c:\myscript.ps1 on that remote machine, I don't get any security warning. What can I do to get the powershell script executed remotely without security warning.

Comment: is there a reason to not use powershell remoting ? Btw your syntax is wrong try with `-file c:\myscript.ps1`

Comment: What is the advantage of 'powershell remoting' over psexec.exe?

Comment: well, at least not using a third party tool. You can try something like .`invoke-command -computername remotecomputer -command {& c:\myscript.ps1}`. Of  course you'll have to [enable remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849694.aspx) first

Comment: How can I specify username and password for my 'remotecomputer' when using 'invoke-command'?

Comment: use the `-credential` parameter and have a look at `get-help invoke-command`